# Exclude a few columns from a grouped selection by `dplyr::contains`

Tags: regex, r, dplyr

Suppose a data frame with several groups of columns (linked by their names, here `Bla` and `D`):

```
df = data.frame(A=1, BlaTata=2, BlaTato=3, BlaTota=4, BlaToto=5, 
                C=6, D1=7, D2=8, D3=9, D4=10)
# A BlaTata BlaTato BlaTota BlaToto C D1 D2 D3 D4
# 1       2       3       4       5 6  7  8  9 10
```

How can I easily drop all columns containing `Bla` (i.e., `select(-contains('Bla'))`) except for a few of them that I would explicitely "protect" from the (de)selection procedure?

Supposing I want to "protect" `BlaTato` and `BlaToto`:

```
df %>% mutate(saveBlaToto=BlaToto, saveBlaTato=BlaTato) %>% 
  select(-starts_with('Bla')) %>% 
  mutate(BlaToto=saveBlaToto, BlaTato=saveBlaTato) %>% 
  select(-contains('save')) %>%
  select(order(colnames(.)))
# A BlaTato BlaToto C D1 D2 D3 D4
# 1       3       5 6  7  8  9 10
```

There must be an easier and more elegant way ;-)

Supposing it is not handy to select by column index etc.

Something like `select(-contains('Bla' but keep c('BlaTato','BlaToto')))` possibly for several columns to be preserved...

---

*EDIT*

This question is answered in Frank's "**New Question**" below.
The original question, simpler and answered in his "**First Question**", was *"How to drop all columns containing `B` except from `B2` in the following data frame"*:

```
df = data.frame(A=1, B1=2, B2=3, B3, B4=5, C=6, D1=7, D2=8, D3=9, D4=10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First question.** If you look at `?select`, you'll see that you can enter a regular expression, like

```
# example
df = data.frame(A=1, B1=2, B2=3, B3=4, B4=5, C=6, D1=7, D2=8, D3=9, D4=10)

# goal: drop B, protect B2
df %>% select(-matches('^B[^2]$'))

  A B2 C D1 D2 D3 D4
1 1  3 6  7  8  9 10
```

*Reading the regex:*

- `^` and `$` indicate start and end of the string.
- `[^x]` means any character except `x`.

**New question.** It looks like dplyr doesn't support Perl-style regexes yet, so...

```
# example
df = data.frame(A=1, BlaTata=2, BlaTato=3, BlaTota=4, BlaToto=5, 
            C=6, D1=7, D2=8, D3=9, D4=10)

# goal: drop Bla, protect BlaTato, BlaToto
df %>% select(-grep('^Bla(?!Tato|Toto)', names(.), perl=TRUE))

  A BlaTato BlaToto C D1 D2 D3 D4
1 1       3       5 6  7  8  9 10
```

*Reading the regex:*

- `(?!xyz)` means "don't be followed by `xyz`"
- `x|y` means `x` or `y`

For more info on regular expressions and the base R functions for using them, read `?regex` and `?grep`. Really, though, you shouldn't name your columns like this. If you find yourself in a position where you need to parse column names, you probably made a mistake earlier on.

Comment: Thanks @Frank - simple and efficient, of course. This is what I was looking for, though I couldn't immediately adapt it to my real case so I edited a bit my question to have a slightly more interesting case. Would it be OK for you to adapt your answer accordingly? Thanks!!

Comment: @ztl Okay, I've added an answer to that version.

Comment: Thanks @Frank! Great! Shall I be vicious to the point of asking how to do if there is a column `BlaTa` to be kept but `BlaTati` to be removed? Looks like `?!Ta` is not `word-only`... Any idea?

Comment: And I totally agree, such names are totally disastrous, but this is how I get my data with so many columns I did not wanted to manually improve them... well maybe I should have!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but it should be possible to do like `(?!Ta$)` with the `$` indicating the end of the string.

Comment: Yes that's it. Problem totally solved then, thanks a lot @Frank!